# How to save the moving graphs in the jupyter notebook into the pdf?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have tried saving the notebook which has moving graphs in form of pdf but the pdf doesn't show any moving graphs, is it possible to save the moving graphs in form of pdf?

Comment: What do you mean by moving? You want interactive graphs in your PDF? Or do you want to insert videos?

Comment: i would like to know if we can get an interactive graph in the pdf

Comment: is there any alternative method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run the following code in your command prompt.

pip install -U notebook-as-pdf

pyppeteer-install

jupyter-nbconvert --to PDFviaHTML example.ipynb

Comment: The result would be called example.pdf as our Jupyter Notebook is called example.ipynb.

Comment: I tried for interactive graphs in pdf but saving it as pdf is the only option

Comment: Here I showed you a trick to convert your Jupyter Notebook into a PDF file. It might be simple but will prove useful in the long run.

Comment: Here I showed you a trick to convert your Jupyter Notebook into a PDF file. It might be simple but will prove useful in the long run.

Comment: or maybe just a normal pdf